# Foreach loop shows the last key in select menu

Tags: php, foreach

i am making a crypto converter as a project for my school. I am using a api key for that and the array of the api is:

```
array(10) {
      ["ADA"]=>
      float(1.024301)
      ["BNB"]=>
      float(402.82399)
      ["BTC"]=>
      float(40678.195596)
      ["DOGE"]=>
      float(0.140886)
      ["ETH"]=>
      float(2877.712908)
      ["LTC"]=>
      float(119.283982)
      ["NEO"]=>
      float(26.72906)
      ["USDT"]=>
      float(1.008932)
      ["XMR"]=>
      float(163.338038)
      ["XRP"]=>
      float(0.780664)
}
```

And this the loop i am using to loop through array in a select menu:

```
<form method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="Enter Amount"><br><br>
            <select name="from">
            <?php
            Foreach ($arr_usd["rates"] as $currency => $rates) {
                print "<option value='$rates'>$currency</option>";
            }
            ?>
            </select>
            <select name="to">
                <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
                <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <button class="btn" name="convert_crypto">Convert</button>
            <div id="result"><?php include "post.php" ?>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The select menu works as it should be, it displays the crypto names. The calculation of the rates works too.
But when i echo the answer, it echoes the last key of the currency in this case XRP.

```
if(isset($_POST['convert_crypto'])) {
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
    if ($to == "USD") {
        $result = ($amount * round($from,2));
        echo $amount . " " . $currency . " = " . $result . " US Dollar";
    }    
}
```

Comment: $currency has not been re-defined anywhere in your third code block, I suspect its retaining its value from the foreach loop in your second code block.

Comment: Can you add the `form` code... or this is on all the same page?

Comment: Change your input to `<option value='$currency'>$currency</option>` so it only posts the currency. Then, when processing the form, do an API lookup to get the rate. This also solves a security issue with your current setup. The client could change the rate in the HTML and post a better rate for themselves.

Comment: @user3783243 added the form code. They are not on the same page. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any `$currency` reference. However, if - and that would make sense here, you have the part of code which prints option tags with the catching POST in the same file, in the same order (printer first, catcher then), then a `$currency` variable is loaded by the very last information it could obtain in the foreach loop.
Normally, you do not want that. I believe you would rather set a 'value' of each option as a currency, and only then, when the form is posted, you load a rate for the selected currency.

**EDIT:** Only parameters within "value" from a form is sent to backend. That means `<option value=rate>currency</option>` will provide only rate, NOT the currency